# Why does "if tty -s" work but "if [ tty -s ]" does not?

Tags: ksh, tty, test

Note, I am using `ksh` and running in CentOS.

I have a shell script where a logger function is set like:

```
if tty -s
then
  echo "${FOO}" | tee -a ${BAR_LOG_FILE}
else
  echo "${FOO}" >> ${BAR_LOG_FILE} 
fi
```

My question is, when I refactored this `if` to look like all the other `if` tests in my code, it stopped functioning.

Why?

My refactor was as follows:

```
if [ tty -s ];
then
  echo "${FOO}" | tee -a ${BAR_LOG_FILE}
else
  echo "${FOO}" >> ${BAR_LOG_FILE} 
fi
```

My only change was to put brackets around the `if` and add a `;`, like the rest of my `if` tests, which all work as intended.

My refactor caused an error which looked like the the `BAR_LOG_FILE` couldn't be found.

What's going on here?

Comment: Can the downvotes be explained? I was able to find other posts dealing with test but unless you realize the [ is a command and not syntax for a test, it would be hard not to get confused by this type of question. And there's from what I can tell, no suitable reference that explains it as it relates to tty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square brackets after `if` aren’t shell syntax which can be ommitted or not depending on stylistic preferences, they’re a separate command, [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html). (The linked manpage describes the external `test`/`[` command, but many shells provide their own implementation.)

Writing

```
if [ tty -s ];
```

is equivalent to writing

```
if test tty -s;
```

and since `test`/`[` doesn’t have a `tty` operator, it fails.

`if` is followed by a command, which it runs, and the exit code of that command determines which branch is taken after the `if`: if it’s 0, the `then` branch is taken, otherwise, the `else` branch (if any).

Comment: OK. This makes sense given all my other `if` commands are followed by flags (e.g. `-f`, `-s`and not commands) and why _they_ work as intended.

Comment: Your other `if` statements *are* followed by a command, the `[` command, and `-f`, `-s` etc. are arguments to `[`.